# Feed import breaks due to ajax error

Tags: feeds

When I tried to do a feed import, I got the following error.

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
> HTTP Result Code: 200
> Debugging information follows.
> Path: /batch?id=1726&op=do
> StatusText: OK
> ResponseText [Omitted text]

(There are quite a few similar errors on the web, for example https://www.drupal.org/node/1125060.)

When I changed the author field to 'site-admin' (see attached image), auto-complete seems running and popup the following error.

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
> HTTP Result Code: 200
> Debugging information follows.
> Path: http://site-prod.local/user/autocomplete
> StatusText: OK
> ResponseText: my_site_name | my_username
>
> [url1]
> [url2]
> [url3]
> [Search form]
> [Primary tab: View (active tab)]
> [Edit]
> [Shortcuts]
> [Broken links]
> [Devel output]
> [My username]
> [Email]
> [Omitted text]

The log message is the following.

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/aegir/platforms/production/drupal-7.27/includes/common.inc:2700) in drupal_goto() (line 703 of /var/aegir/platforms/production/drupal-7.27/includes/common.inc).

If I put `exit()` right after `drupal_json_output()`. The related problem seems resolving itself.

When I run `drush -d -v search-index`, the indexing stuck at around 61%. This indicates some problems with a node.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Looks like the request returns something which isn't a feed. Does "lots of text" mean lots of HTML markup?  You may be able to find out what the remote site is saying by reading through it.

Comment: Actually, there is no markup (or is it stripped?), but text about google tag manger javascript code, some user info e.g. (Member for
2 years 6 months), following by the website menu links

Comment: @Ollie, also see my update at "Update for Main error 2015-05-22" and "Update for Related Error 2015-05-22" above

Comment: Ok but you should probably call drupal_exit() rather than exit(). What's happening is that Drupal is sending your json over to the page theming system, adding headers, footers etc. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_exit/7

Answer (score 0):

By using xdebug and vdebug (plugin for vim), I am able to step into the code and ping point the issue.

In https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_cron_run/7

I put a watchdog: `watchdog('bug_cron', '<pre>'. print_r($module, true). '</pre>');` inside.

```
// Iterate through the modules calling their cron handlers (if any):
foreach (module_implements('cron') as $module) {
      // Do not let an exception thrown by one module disturb another.
      try {
        // NOTE: put a watchdog and look at your log message. 
        // You should able to see which module causes issues.
        watchdog('bug_cron', '<pre>'. print_r($module, true). '</pre>');


        module_invoke($module, 'cron');
      }
      catch (Exception $e) {
        watchdog_exception('cron', $e);
      }
    }
```

It is the search module causes issues. Disable it, then uninstall the setting via **the drupal menu GUI**, then it is fixed, but I am not sure why search module causes issues.

**Updated at 2015-05-26**

It turns out my module uses hook_url_inbound_alter + drupal_goto caused issues. It is not easy to debug, because there are couple of side effects.